# Access Gmail's IMAP using AssertionFlowClient and service account

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, gmail-imap, google-api-dotnet-client

Is it possible to use AssertionFlowClient and service account to access mailbox of any user in my domain through IMAP. Same as with 2-legged OAuth 1.0.

Here's my code:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate =  new X509Certificate2(...)
AuthorizationServerDescription server = new AuthorizationServerDescription {...};
List<string> scope = new List<string> { 
    "https://mail.google.com/", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo#email" };

AssertionFlowClient provider = new AssertionFlowClient(server, certificate)
{
  ServiceAccountId = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
  Scope = string.Join(" ",scope.ToArray()),
};

IAuthorizationState grantedAccess = AssertionFlowClient.GetState(provider);
accessToken = grantedAccess.AccessToken;

using (Imap client = new Imap())
{
    client.ConnectSSL("imap.gmail.com");
    client.LoginOAUTH2("user@mydomain.com", accessToken);
    ...
}
```

I'm able to retrieve valid accessToken from accounts.google.com server (although AssertionFlowClient/DotNetOpenAuth has a bug and currently I use debugger and watch window to retrieve it).

**I'm sure that accessToken is correct**, as I can query www.googleapis.com/userinfo/email API endpoint using it - it returns the same value as SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL.

Gmail's IMAP server returns the following **error** however:

```
{"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}
```

"Manage API client access" for this service account is configured to "Email (Read/Write/Send)  https://mail.google.com/" on cpanel.

AssertionFlowClient/DotNetOpenAuth bug indicates that no-one has ever tried this.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems Google forgot to include this little detail in their documentation:

```
AssertionFlowClient provider = new AssertionFlowClient(server, certificate)
    {
        ServiceAccountId = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
        Scope = "https://mail.google.com/",
        ServiceAccountUser = "user@mydomain.com",  // <- important
    };
```

It also seems that requesting access to multiple scopes (space separated) fails.